# How to substract day from date in a Java Persistence Query?

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, ejb-3.0, jpql

I am looking for a way to list all items that are 10 days (for instance, my case would be a parameter for the threshold) old using a Java Peristence Query.

My Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT item
FROM Item item
INNER JOIN item.flags flag
WHERE flag.tspDate ............ :intDaysThreshold
```

I would like to be able to do something similar to what we can do in PostgreSQL using INTERVAL.

Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cannot be done in JPQL-query because it does not support date arithmetic of any kind. Fallback options are:

1. native SQL query
2. use of extensions possibly available in implementation (for example [FUNC](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.1.0/JPAQueryEnhancements) in EclipseLink)
3. querying larger datasets and performing calculations in Java
4. often (if condition is relative to current date) it is possible to construct query in such a form, that parameter can be calculated in Java side (date that is 10 days in past for example).